# Compiling using eclipsec.exe fails but using the IDE it pass

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to create a CI process to a c code,
The developers are working on an IDE called "Kinetis" and when I ran and compiled the project from the IDE everything is working fine.

To create the CI I tried to compile the project using eclipsec.exe and then I get an error:

```
c:\jenkins\workspace\embeded_build\ng_brg_plt_env\mqx\source\io\flash_spi\flash_spi.h:19:20: fatal error: device.h: No such file or directory
 #include <device.h>
```

The device.h file exists in :

**C:\jenkins\workspace\Embeded_Build\NG_BRG_PLT_ENV\config\twrk65f180m\device.h**

Is there something missing in the command line? I couldn't find an argument to pass the classpath, and I don't even know if this will help.

https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html

This is the command I am running:

```
eclipsec.exe -nosplash  -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -import .\ -build mqtt -cleanBuild mqtt
```

Comment: The `\\` in the command line looks odd. See also https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/advanced/headless-builds/

Comment: Turns out I didn't specify the configuration in the CMD that I wanted to run with, 
So I needed to run: eclipsec.exe -nosplash  -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -import .\ -build mqtt -cleanBuild mqtt -configuration debug

Comment: As a side-note, you should consider placing the register maps etc in the local project. Particularly if you include non-standard headers from application code (device.h being the register map). Relying on some C:\ compiler installation of libs is very bad practice. Import all source into the local project.